# how to use class library in my .net core web application using vscode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am developing web application using .net core with visual studio code[vscode]. i need to know how to call class library in my web application? if its possible to convert class library as nuget package and also how to add converted nuget package?

or any other way to call class library in my web application[vscode].

Comment: for debugging you could add it to your web app solution and reference it. copy references when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how to add reference to a class library from your application project, you can use [the `dotnet add reference` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference).

For a detailed tutorial that includes adding a reference, have a look at [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-macos).